# calculate possible combinations between multiple arrays

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm making a question list. There are 3 questions, each with 4 answers. I'm trying to calculate which combinations are possible.

There should be 4x4x4 (=64) possible combinations. And I expect an array like this [1,1,1] (user answers all 3 questions with the first answer).

I see that ruby has a nice permatation method, but it's not permatiation. The combination method, only takes 1 array to an account.

So in short, I have 3 array, each with [1,2,3,4] and I like 64 arrays with every combination

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`Array#product`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Array.html#method-i-product) method.

```
[1,2,3,4].product([1,2,3,4],[1,2,3,4]).size # => 64
```

I used `Array#size` to show you, that 64 combinations are being generated.

Answer (score 1):

If the number of answers to all questions is the same you can calculate the number of possible combinations by using number of answers raised to the number of questions. The ruby code for that would be:

```
answer_count = 4
question_count = 3
combinations = answer_count**question_count
```

If the number of answers to each question is different you can count them and then multiply them for your answer (as you were on the road to doing in your question). For example if you have 3 questions and the first has 4 answers, the second has 5 answers and the third has 3 answers you could do something like this:

```
answer_counts = [4, 5, 3]
answer_counts.inject(1) {|product, answers| product * answers}
```